# Is stuff in a github private repository compromised?

Tags: git, github

I've been learning about how to use gitHub from Visual Studio Code.

I didn't realised that my repo didn't have a .gitignore file.

So I did a git push and everything went to the online private repo.

After it was uploaded, I realised the mistake and deleted the whole online repo (only a couple of minutes passed).

Not I've done everything again, this time adding a gitignore file.

The only file that was uploaded was one with my email password that after the incident I changed it anyway, but I'm interested to know from a theoretical perspective.

Is that considered a security breach?

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering it was a private repository you should not have any problems at all. However, it is not encrypted so it is easy to mess up and leak the info, it is not the case as you have already deleted the repository, so do not worry, you are safe.

Answer (score 1):

The question to ask is whether GitHub employees can access the private repo.

They could perhaps be doing that for record-keeping, fixing bugs, improving usability or for a myriad of reasons.

Would need to review the user agreements and so on.

**So in a nutshell**, if the password that you use is a shared password with multiple other places such as other websites etc., you need to change them all and review the practice of sharing passwords. On the other hand, even if the password is not shared, **you need to change** it which I see you have.

It would be **considered a security breach** in situations if this was your corporate email password and it was leaked. And you would be required to report it. Just one example. Since this is your personal email password, you can get by by changing it and to learn to never put sensitive information on the web.

Do not know who downvoted this question, it is a perfectly legit one. But that is my opinion.